# Retrieve output message from sqlserver procedure in php

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I have this procedure in SQL Server where functions are executed, and I want to collect the output in PHP.

The problem is that the first result that it returns is the "result" and then it returns another one with the outputs.

How can I collect these outputs?

Thank you

```
 DECLARE @NETO FLOAT
 DECLARE @DTO1 FLOAT
 DECLARE @DTO2 FLOAT
 DECLARE @DTO3 FLOAT
 DECLARE @CODIGO NVARCHAR(50)
 DECLARE @CODIGOEAN NVARCHAR(50)
 DECLARE @NOMBRE NVARCHAR(50)
 
 EXEC dbo.Precio, '.$IDCliente.', @NETO OUTPUT, @DTO1 OUTPUT,@DTO2 OUTPUT,@DTO3 OUTPUT,@CODIGO OUTPUT,@CODIGOEAN OUTPUT,@NOMBRE OUTPUT
 
 select @NETO as neto, @DTO1, @DTO2, @DTO3, @CODIGO, @CODIGOEAN, @NOMBRE
```

```
    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($pc, $sql);
    sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
       
    do {
        $data=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);
        sqlsrv_next_result($stmt);
    } while (sqlsrv_next_result($stmt)); 
    
    echo json_encode($data);
```

That it returned me result

Comment: You're executing `sqlsrv_next_result()` twice, at the end of the loop body and once again at the loop condition, so you're skipping the actual result.

Comment: Why do you pass a string literal `'.$IDCliente.'` as first parameter in the stored procedure? Are you trying to execute this T-SQL script in PHP to get the values of all output parameters of the stored procedure? Please, edit the question and include the whole PHP statement.

Answer (score 0):

The first "result" is the number of rows affected by the T-SQL sentences. It is returned as part of the results by default. To deactivate this, try: `set nocount on`, just after the declaration of your procedure. For example:

```sql
create procedure [ProcedureName]
  @Params
  as
  set nocount on
```